# Inequality for the measure of a set

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(X)=1$. Let $f \in L^{p}(X)$ for $1<p<\infty$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<t<\|f\|_{1}$. Then for $q \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $1/q+1/p=1$ we have:

\begin{equation}
\mu(\{x:|f(x)|\geq t\}) \geq \bigg(\frac{\|f\|_{1}-t}{\|f\|_{p}}\bigg)^{q}
\end{equation}

Could you please provide me a hint on how to prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=\mathbb{I}(|f| \geq t)$.
\begin{align*}
 \|fg\|_1 
 &\leq \|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{q}
 & \text{Holder's inequality} \\
 \|g\|_q  
 &\geq \frac{\|fg\|_1}{\|f\|_{p}} \\
 \mu(x: |f(x)| \geq t))^{q^{-1}}
 &\geq \frac{\int_{|f| \geq t}|f(x)|d\mu}{\|f\|_{p}} \\
 \mu(x: |f(x)| \geq t))
 &\geq \left(\frac{\int_{X}|f(x)|d\mu-\int_{|f| < t}|f(x)|d\mu}{\|f\|_{p}}\right)^{q} \\
 \mu(x: |f(x)| \geq t))
 &\geq \left(\frac{\|f\|_1-\int_{|f| < t}|f(x)|d\mu}{\|f\|_{p}}\right)^{q} \\
 \mu(x: |f(x)| \geq t))
 &\geq \left(\frac{\|f\|_1-t\mu(x: |f(x)| < t)}{\|f\|_{p}}\right)^{q} \\
 \mu(x: |f(x)| \geq t))
 &\geq \left(\frac{\|f\|_1-t}{\|f\|_{p}}\right)^{q}
 & \mu(X)=1
\end{align*}